# Nivo Slider not working on Laravel-5

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I followed this [guide](http://www.jqueryscript.net/slider/nivo-slider.html) and loaded everything. Everything so far works, but the background url doesn't seem to work on any css file. I am adding my source code. I've researched about 50 posts, but neither one discuss about how to get this right.

My code. I've tried both (../images and (/images and they don't work.

```
.theme-default .nivoSlider {
    position:relative;
    background:#fff url(../images/loading.gif) no-repeat 50% 50%;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px 0px #4a4a4a;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px 0px #4a4a4a;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px 0px #4a4a4a;
```

Files are in /images/loading.gif

Comment: Where is your CSS code placed? Where is the `/images` directory with respect to the project directory structure?

Comment: css code is in public/css/defaul.css

Comment: And where the `/images` directory is?

Comment: It's in public/images

Comment: `url(../images/loading.gif)` seems ok to me... have you checked the directory and file permissions to see if the web server can read that file? Also use the browser debugger to see if there are errors there.

Comment: yes. I have tried everything. Marked as resource route and source route . Nothing works. Do you have a suggestion for a slider ?

Comment: In the past I used carouFredSel for some projects and was ok, but I didn't use Laravel at that time.

Comment: Uhm... did you placed anything about your public directory in the `routes.php` file? Could you update your question with the routes? I'm thinking the problem is there.

Comment: Well it's a controller. It shouldn't require anything more than ('/') route

Comment: Ok, I don't have any clue, sorry!

Comment: I think @MarcoPallante might be on the right track... from your comment above it sounds like you might be trying to set up a route for your assets - this is not necessary. There should be no references to your assets in the `routes.php` file.

Comment: The "Marked as resource route and source route" sentence made me thought of a routing problem, but we can't say without the `routes.php` content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these links into page head

```
{!! HTML::style('css/default.css') !!}
```

Copy these files to /css/js and link them to your page:

```
{!! HTML::script('css/js/jquery.nivo.slider.js') !!}
{!! HTML::script('css/js/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js') !!}
```

Then copy this into index page or view :

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
    <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider"> 
    <img src="../images/toystory.jpg" data-thumb="../images/toystory.jpg" alt="" /> 
    <a href="http://dev7studios.com"><img src="../images/up.jpg" data-thumb="../images/up.jpg" alt="" title="This is an example of a caption" /></a> 
     <img src="../images/walle.jpg" data-thumb="../images/walle.jpg" alt="" data-transition="slideInLeft" /> 
     <img src="../images/nemo.jpg" data-thumb="../images/nemo.jpg" alt="" title="#htmlcaption" /> 
</div>
<div id="htmlcaption" class="nivo-html-caption"> 
<strong>This</strong> is an example of a <em>HTML</em> caption with 
<a href="#">a link</a>. </div>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(window).load(function() {
        $('#slider').nivoSlider();
     });
</script> 

<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-36251023-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'jqueryscript.net']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

 (function() {
      var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
      ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
   var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
 })();

</script>
```

Comment: Check if you can add the link for that image on page and if you can see the image.  Then check if CSS clases is correct  -- .theme-default .nivoSlider

Comment: Yes it's accessible via direct linking.

Comment: What about div CSS classes

Comment: yea it worked as an 'ID' via JS. Thanks for your help.